# Harmonic Differential forms with respect to different metrics

Tags: riemannian-geometry

For a closed Riemannian Manifold with two metrics $g$ and $h$, the harmonic k-forms decompose into
$$\Omega^k=\mathcal{H_g}+d^*_g(\Omega^{k+1})+d(\Omega^{k-1})$$ 
And
$$\Omega^k=\mathcal{H_h}+d^*_h(\Omega^{k+1})+d(\Omega^{k-1})$$
My question is, wether (it should certainly be true) there is, and how to explicitly find an isomorphism between these subspaces. There is a related question wether the projection would do – But I would need explicit dependence on the metric for my purposes. My attempt doesn't go futher then the observation that: $$\omega\in\mathcal{H}_g\implies d^*_h(*_h*_g\omega)=0$$ But I cannot prove and am not sure wether also $d(*_h*_g\omega)=0$, which would imply that $\omega\in\mathcal{H}$.

Comment: If you compute the case $h = \lambda g$ for some conformal factor $\lambda > 0$, you see that $*_h *_g = \lambda^{k - n/2}$ acting as multiplication by scalar, which implies that $d(*_h *_g \omega) \neq 0$ in general for $\omega \in \mathcal{H}_g$. ($n$ is the dimension of your manifold)